# How can i return an array in java that is accessible by other objects?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I want to return an array that is accessible by other objects after having read a text file. My instruction parsing class is:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Instruction {
   public String[] instructionList;

   public String[] readFile() throws IOException {
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("directions.txt");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

      int n = 5;
      instructionList = new String[n];

      for (int j = 0; j < instructionList.length; j++) {
          instructionList[j] = br.readLine();
      }
      in.close();   
      return instructionList;
  }
```

}

The above takes in a text file with 5 lines of text in it. In my main() I want to run that function and have the string array be accessible to other objects.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class RoverCommand {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Instruction directions = new Instruction();
      directions.readFile();

      String[] directionsArray;
      directionsArray = directions.returnsInstructionList();

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(directionsArray));
  }
```

}

What's the best way to do that? I would need the elements of the array to be integers if they are numbers and strings if they are letters. P.S. I'm brand new to Java. is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to read a text file, store the contents of that file in an array, and have that array accessible to other objects. I am attempting to do that Mars Rover coding challenge. I also have no experience in Java.

Comment: Does your code work? This seems like a fine way to do it. Alternatively, you can return the array directly from `readFile()`, but this is a design decision that depends on other constraints.

Comment: yes it does, I have no changed it so that readFile() returns the array directly.

Comment: What is the best way to make that array accessible to other objects within main?

Comment: @mendoncakr : don't use an array for that (read my comment on wrongAnswer's answer). Plus, make the variables static if you need to access it in other methods.

Comment: @Dici I strongly disagree with the suggestion to make the variable `static`. Beginners should **never** use `static` variables.

Comment: "What is the best way to make that array accessible to other objects within main?" You can pass the array from `main()` to other constructors or methods.

Comment: So if another object wants to, say access the third element of instructions, how can I pass it to the other object?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : this is just a short problem to solve in a single file. There is no design choice to do, it's just an algorithm to find. As far as I'm concerned, when I solve basic problems or even some mor complex interview questions, I often write my whole code in the main and sometimes in some static methods.

Comment: @Dici There are always design decisions, even for simple problems. Deciding to write all of your code in `main()` **is a design decision**.

Comment: @mendoncakr That depends on how you design the other object's class. Does it need access to **all** of the instructions or just to the third one?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : You know what I want to say. I mean that there is no real OOP issues in that kind of algorithmic problems (no need to reusability, no need to flexibility, no need to encapsulation, no need to create classes...) so having static variables is just fine.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The other object will need to access the 1st and 2nd elements. Another object will need to access the 3rd and 4th.

Comment: @mendoncakr Then you can pass those elements individually as parameters, either to a method or to a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use generics. I try to catch exceptions in the accessors and return null if anything blows up. So you can test if the value returned is null before proceeding.

```
// Client.java
import java.io.IOException;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            InstructionList il = new InstructionList();
            il.readFile("C:\\testing\\ints.txt", 5);

            int[] integers = il.getInstructionsAsIntegers();

            if (integers != null) {
                for (int i : integers) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle
        }
    }
}


// InstructionList.java
import java.io.*;

public class InstructionList {
    private String[] instructions;

    public void readFile(String path, int lineLimit) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        instructions = new String[lineLimit];

        for (int i = 0; i < lineLimit; i++) {
            instructions[i] = br.readLine();
        }

        in.close();
    }

    public String[] getInstructionsAsStrings() {
        return instructions; // will return null if uninitialized
    }

    public int[] getInstructionsAsIntegers() {
        if (this.instructions == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int[] instructions = new int[this.instructions.length];

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < instructions.length; i++) {
                instructions[i] = new Integer(this.instructions[i]);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null; // data integrity fail, return null
        }

        return instructions;
    }
}
```

Comment: While the OP's code can be improved with some basic exception handling (especially to avoid resource leaks), this doesn't address the original question regarding design issues.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm not really sure what he's having trouble with. If he needs one object to access the first and second elements, he can just use the index operator[] to get those. Like `getInstructionsAsIntegers()[1]`. What is your solution to his problem?

Comment: I probably would save the return value in a variable and then index it, rather than indexing the method call directly.

Comment: It seems that the OP's problems are centered around understanding how to use objects and methods (and designing the classes in the first place).

Comment: Not a bad idea, except for when you need to index the integers. You would need a collection for both strings and integers. But it's great for removing the overhead of future calls to getInstructionsAsDataType(). He did say he was new to Java, but I don't know if he is new to object-oriented programming in general. I think he's just asking the Java community here if there is a better alternative to what he is doing. `What's the best way to do that?` But I could be wrong.

Comment: ` I think he's just asking the Java community here if there is a better alternative to what he is doing.` I agree with this assessment, but I also read the question as the OP being new to OOP in general as well

Comment: @scottyeatscode I'm a noob to Java, however not to OOP, my background is in Ruby. Java seems to really be helping with OOP design as literally everything seems to be an object. So is there a better way do read this file and present its contents to other objects? I have 5 lines total, and need to provide every 2 after the first element to a new object.

Comment: @mendoncakr Welcome to the wonderful world of Java! And this is exactly the way I would do it if I were trying to read line by line. There is overhead in the call to getInstructionsAsIntegers() but it's pretty minimal. What Code-Apprentice said about storing it in a variable to be indexed later is not a bad idea, but it means you'll have a collection for each datatype you need. Anyway, the convention for providing data to another class is with get/set accessors and mutators. There are a lot of ways to pass around data. But this is the way I would do it. I'd say you're off to a good start!

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that readFile is called before returnsInstructionList is invoked. Leaving you returnsInstructionList returning null.

I would :

```
public String[] getContentsFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

  int n = 5;
  instructionList = new String[n];

  for (int j = 0; j < instructionList.length; j++) {
      instructionList[j] = br.readLine();
  }
  in.close();       
  return instructionList;
}
```

Part two to the question you can use generics. To achieve what you want but you have to incorporate a way to say what it is.

Eg

```
public class Foo {
   public ReturnForFoo returnAStringOrIntger(boolean val) {
      if(val){
         return new ReturnForFoo("String", ValueType.STRING) ;
      }
      return new ReturnForFoo(10, ValueType.INTEGER); //int
   } 
}

 public class ReturnForFoo {
     Object value;
     ValueType type;

     public ReturnForFoo(Object value, ValueType type) {
         this.value=value;
         this.type=type
     }
     // Asume you have getters for both value and value type
     public static ENUM ValueType {
          STRING,
          INTEGER,
          UNKNOWN
     }
 }
```

This code is in your main.

```
 Foo foo = new Foo();
 String value;
 int val;
 ReturnForFoo returnForFoo = foo.returnAStringOrIntger(true);
 // NOTE you can use switch instead of if's and else if's. It will be better
 if(returnForFoo.getValueType().equals(ValueType.INTEGER)){
    val = (int) returnForFoo.getValue();
 } else if(returnForFoo.getValueType().equals(ValueType.STRING)){
    value = (String) returnForFoo.getValue(); 
 } else {
    // UNKOWN Case
 }
```

Comment: The first sentence is wrong and the last part is a nasty solution.

Comment: @Dici can you help us improve the answer as to how we can use generics.

Comment: Well, I read the description of the problem and it seems to be a bad idea to store all the lines in a single array. It would be more logical to parse the file with a `Scanner` and store the values in some variables of the expected type, since you know precisely how the input looks like.

Comment: Im taking about a function returning generics and not file addling and how to store the file. is there a better way to do this  Another approach i know is that we can wrap the return into a new class which has an enum of type. I want to know a better way of doing generics.

Comment: An array of `Object` is not generic, genericity is about writing some code depending on an unknown type taken as parameter. In my opinion you should not try to store `Integer`s and `String`s in the same data structure in the first place, so I won't propose any solution to do it.

Comment: What if the source of data is not know but the give it to you in that format it is often the case. If you are using multiple 3 party API one of the give you a string and other gives you Integer and so on ...are you telling me you are going to write code for all of them separately? Or impel meant a central way and then based on the input fluctuate the code flow.

Comment: In this particular case, the OP wants to store Strings, so the data type **is** known.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The OP said 'I would need the elements of the array to be integers if they are numbers and strings if they are letters.'

Answer (score 0):

check instructionList is null or not. if it is null, call readFile method.

```
public String[] returnsInstructionList() {
      if (instructionList== null){
          try { readFile(); } catch(Exception e){}
      }
      return instructionList;
}
```

because of readFile can throw exception, it would be good to use one extra variable. like:

```
private boolean fileReaded = false;
public String[] returnsInstructionList() {
      if (!fileReaded){
          fileReaded = true;
          try { readFile(); } catch(Exception e){}
      }
      return instructionList;
}
```

and if readFile can be run concurrently, easiest way to make function synchronized, like

```
private boolean fileReaded = false;
public synchronized void readFile() throws IOException {
    .
    .
    .        
}
public synchronized String[] returnsInstructionList() {
      if (!fileReaded){
          fileReaded = true;
          try { readFile(); } catch(Exception e){}
      }
      return instructionList;
}
```